# PDO Prepared Statements and MSSQL databases not functioning correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, database, pdo

I'm having a problem running prepared queries on a MSSQL database using PDO. I can connect to the database and run SELECT queries with no parameters, but now I'm trying to run a simple SELECT query with one parameter, :user. However, the code does not return any values, despite the fact that there definitely is a database row with that value in. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName.';charset=utf8mb4',$dbUser, $dbPass);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email_address = :user ');
$stmt->bindValue(":user", $_SESSION["username"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

I receive no output from the var_dump. I know that in the database there is a correct row, so I tried:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email_address = 'the@email.com'");
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

And yet still no value was returned. Am I doing something wrong with PDO? If I type this exact query into the query bar it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to execute your query.

right after the paramter binding, put this code:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot. Forgot to execute the query. Amended code for people in the same predicament:

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName.';charset=utf8mb4',$dbUser,  $dbPass);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email_address = :user ');
$stmt->bindValue(":user", $_SESSION["username"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```